# jQuery cross fade slideshow bug

Tags: jquery

HI have created a cross-fade slideshow witch I have been trying to create for some time now being a beginner it took more then I expected and while I was celebrating that it was finally done I realized the slider had a bug here is the code:

[slideshow code](http://jsfiddle.net/ESBVV/3/)

If I click the button for `NEXT` or `PREV` the SlideShow starts taking speed in the time it's changing the images every time I click on them.Can anyone take a look at my code and tell me what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**:I have added images.The problem with the code is that each time you click on next or prev the images start sliding faster and faster by default it should change an image every 4 seconds but after you click a few times on next or prev the speed in wich the images change increases.

Comment: It would help if your jsFiddle actually worked.

Comment: what is not working?I know there are no images but I don't know how to add them

Comment: A) You can use images from a third party site and B) the fiddle doesn't do anything and just throws errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/qve6z/
Here is a working code!
I was:

1. Moved your next and prev functions into $(function(){...}); body
2. Added ; to end of the statements where missing
3. Changed the order of your functions, declare first, call it second
4. Changed setIntervals from `setInterval("functionname()",1000)` to `setInterval(functionname,1000)`
5. Moved the first setInterval after function declarations.

I was changed your images to text (1,2,3,4), it was only for testing.

Comment: the slider still keeps taking speed after I click a few times on next or prev

Comment: remove setInterval(...) from `next` and `prev`.
Whenever you click on next or prev, a new setInterval is setted.